# Change background image smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to make changing background effect append to the body when page scrolls within specific amount which scroll at 50%,20%,10% rate of page

Here is what i got so far [Full Screen Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nucleo1985/L3HzS/1/embedded/result/)

Below is the sample code :

HTML :

```
<div>
   <p>...</p>
   <!-- more <p> elements below -->
</div>
```

And the script :

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
   var JarakScroll = 200; // jarak scrol
   var JumlahJarakPasScroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
   if (JumlahJarakPasScroll > JarakScroll) {
       jQuery('html').addClass('scrolled');
   } else {
       jQuery('html').removeClass('scrolled');
   }
});
```

The background was changing but with no effect, anyone can help applying nice effect ?

Comment: What type of effect do you want? A fade?

Comment: Any, as long as its smooth. Not specifically.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the background image to change with a nice effect it might be better if you have the background images applied to two divs that have 100% width and 100%height of the body and are placed correctly with z-index.

More specifically, place the first div on top of the second div and when you want the background image to change, fadeOut the first div. That'll be a neat effect. I'm assuming you can code this on your ownn.